# "Argument not valid" after running it correctly. Ideas on how to MAKE A COPY of a SPECIFIC SPREADSHEET (not a sheet, but the entire file)?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, file-rename

I am having trouble creating a spreadsheet using names defined in cells within a specific file (also a spreadsheet)...

Full code below:

```
function defineNames() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1d6lw9R4WaPUCyHWcBRr8xDyZFjBNvUMH6BE_U2NXB8Q");

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  var values = range.getValues();

// FOR LOOP para identificar nombre, y crear documentos con ese nombre, y escribir el URL del nuevo doc en la columna 7)
  for (i=2;i<=values.length;i++) {
  var nameVariable = values[i][5];

//AFTER RUNNING... IT SAYS THIS ARGUMENT IS NOT VALID... EVEN THOUGH IT DID EVERYTHING IT NEEDED TO DO.
      new_ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(nameVariable); 

// Get the URL of the document.
  var url = new_ss.getUrl();

// Copiar el URL del nuevo documento en la columna 7
  var rangeoverwrite = sheet.getRange(i+1, 7);
  // SetValue escribe lo que le digamos, en el "range" que definimos arriba...
  rangeoverwrite.setValue(url);
  }
}
```

I am also trying to "MAKE A COPY of" a specific Spreadsheet in my drive, and changing the name of the "COPY OF ..." I created using values within a specific cell as the names to be used to rename the files..... 
Any help if much appreciated
MANY THANKS!